# ASP.NET MVC3 HttpPost + jquery ajax multithreading?

Tags: ajax

For example, there is a Register button, when the button is clicked, it will send an ajax request to the Action Register to do the database processing and then send verification email.

```
$.ajax({
    url: "/Register",
    type: 'POST',
    error: function(xhr) {},
    success: function(data) {
       //after success, change the button color                   
    }
});

[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Register() { 
     //database processing
     ......
    //send email 
    //(this step takes long period of time, the button wait for long time to change the color, how can i solve this issue?)
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

when you call a long processing operation from a web page you so not want to wait for it to finish. so what you do is add the long processing tasks to a queue and return. you can use something like MSMQ or you can build simple queue mechanism yourself, i.e. insert a record for the email you want to send in a table and then have some other process look at that table and send the emails...

Comment: Thanks, MSMQ is the solution!!